# OverFast API ( info.map is not a function ) when I query the details of a hero React.js

Tags: reactjs, api

Good evening, I've been going around in circles for some time on this problem that I've already solved on other use cases, but I can't find the source of the problem.
Of course, without using the .map function it doesn't work.

Here is the code of the component in question

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
// import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

function Heroes({ heroes }) {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const getHeroDetail = () => {
    axios.get(`/heroes/${heroes.key}`).then((res) => setInfo(res.data));
    axios.get(`/heroes/${heroes.key}`).then((res) => console.log(res.data.media));
  };
  const wrapperFunction = () => {
    handleOpen();
    getHeroDetail();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="hero_profile"
        onClick={wrapperFunction}
        heroes={heroes}
        key={heroes.key}
      >
        <img src={heroes.portrait} alt={heroes.name} />
        <p>{heroes.name}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="modal_container">
        <Modal
          className="modal"
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        >
          <Box className="modal_info">
            {info.map((infos) => (
                <p>{infos.role}</p>
            ))}
            
            
            
         
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Heroes;
```

I successfully retrieved all the heroes, but I'm stuck on their details for some reason. Thanks for your help!

I tried to change the type of state ( array or string ) but it doesn't seem to work.

Response is a data [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSWnS.png)

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: https://overfast-api.tekrop.fr/#tag/Heroes/operation/list_roles_heroes_roles_get  Except with the console.log, it doesn't work :/

Comment: I don’t see a “data” property, and “role” doesn’t seem to be an array.

Comment: When I log with only the answer, it is indeed a data that appears, I edit the post to show you

Comment: Finally, i found, this is a object and i succesfully get data ( name, role...) ^^ Thanks !!

Comment: Glad you worked it out :)